# Issue with route resolver

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a lazy-loaded route with resolver:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: MyComponent,
        resolve: {
          data: MyService
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MyRoutingModule {}
```

My module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MyRoutingModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    MyComponent,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [MyService]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

My service `resolver`:

```
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    return forkJoin(
      this.getData1(),
      this.getData2(),
      this.getData3()
    );
  }
```

I am subscribing to the property `data` on my app component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(x => {
      data = x; //x = undefined
    });
  }
}
```

The problems is `x` is always `undefined`
Any ideas why I can not access to my resolved data and how to fix that ?

UPDATE:
I want to know when data resolved so I want to hide the spinner.
As per @OneLunch-Man post my app component won't have an access to that data, so how would you work that out, all I need to know on my app component is when data has being resolved so I can do some UI state changes like hiding a spinner, etc

Comment: Q: What exactly is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @paulsm4 I wan't to know when data resolved so I want to hide the spinner.

Comment: Q: Could you leverage Angular lifecycle events to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

AppComponent is outside of the router-outlet and does not have access to this data.
Only the child components of a route have access to that.

Comment: Is there any way to know on app component that data has being resolved?  I wan't to know when data resolved so I want to hide the spinner.

Comment: Personally, I keep my spinners within the child components. 

There are plenty of options, but there isn't one "set way" to do it and I'm not a huge fan of the global loader over localized loaders (opinion).

- One way is you can have a service with a subject/observable and when the data resolves on the child, hit the service method to change the subject (that'll trigger the observable to hide the spinner).

Comment: Yeah just implemented that as a service. BTW, why the `router-outlet` does not have access to this data?

Comment: Do you mean why can't the component containing the router-outlet bind to an output event from the router-outlet, or why can't the component containing the router-outlet have that data injected as a dependency?

Comment: Just asking to provide a bit more background on your answer.

Comment: Oh, sure. So the component containing the router-outlet (app component usually) has already been constructed. When you navigate, the containing component is not rebuilt, the content within router-outlet is changed to that new component in the path. So, those components declared in the routes are what can access the ActivatedRoute provided (I believe at) the router-outlet level (below the containing component). This is because they are reconstructed and their dependencies injected at this time.

Comment: You may actually be able to bind to events on router-outlet: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet had to look that up. Within your app component, you may be able to change your resolver to a promiseAll, convert those observables to promises, and use the `activate` event on the router-outlet to fire a function in the app-component

Answer (score 1):

You can hide and show the spinner Using Router Events. And routerEvent also has a ResolveStart and ResolveEnd instance use that as per your need

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: Event) => {
      if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this.loading = true;
    }
    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd ||
        routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel ||
        routerEvent instanceof NavigationError) {
      this.loading = false;
    }
    });
  }
```

Ref:https://angular.io/api/router/RouterEvent#subclasses